# Masking Name with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna mask a name with the provisions that if there are more than 4 letters it will form the following masking :

```
Jason Mamoa ---> Ja**n Ma**a
```

I have tried this :

```
var name ="Jason Mamoa";
var regex =/\b[^\W]{2}([^\W]{2,})[^\W]\b/g;
console.log(nama.replace(regex,"**$1*"));
```

but the opposite happened, like this :

```
Jason Mamoa --> **so* **mo*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go the other way around - capture the first two letters, and the last letter, and replace with them separated by `**`:

```js
var name ="Jason Mamoa";
var regex =/\b(\w{2})\w+(\w)\b/g;
console.log(name.replace(regex, '$1**$2'));
```

If you want the resulting string to be the same length as the original, use a replacer function:

```js
var name ="Jason Mammmmoa";
var regex =/\b(\w{2})(\w+)(\w)\b/g;
console.log(name.replace(
  regex,
  (_, first, middle, last) => `${first}${'*'.repeat(middle.length)}${last}`
));
```

Note that `[^\W]` is equivalent to `\w`.

To also mask the last 2 characters of 3 and 4 character names, capture up to 2 leading characters, and have the `last` be optional:

```js
var name ="Eli Mose";
var regex =/\b(\w{1,2})(\w{2,}?)(\w?)\b/g;
console.log(name.replace(
  regex,
  (_, first, middle, last) => `${first}${'*'.repeat(middle.length)}${last}`
));
```

Comment: what if in one word there are 3-4 letters it will make masking as follows: `Eli Mose ---> E** Mo**`

Comment: You said in your question that you only wanted masking for 5+ characters?

Comment: if there are several conditions

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my question